# Spring Rest modifying fields in the returned JSON

Tags: java, spring, rest, pagination

I'm working in a microservices architecture project, where i've been trying to solve a problem with the pagination return of one of them, facing a different json structure of return ONLY in one of the services.

That's the normal structure

```
...
"pageable": {
    "page": 0,
    "size": 2147483647,
    "sort": {
      "orders": [
        {
          "direction": "DESC",
          "property": "id",
          "ignoreCase": false,
          "nullHandling": "NATIVE"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "total": 1
...
```

That's the different one

```
...
"pageable": {
    "sort": {
      "sorted": true,
      "unsorted": false,
      "empty": false
    },
    "pageSize": 10,
    "pageNumber": 0,
    "offset": 0,
    "unpaged": false,
    "paged": true
  },
  "totalPages": 2,
  "totalElements": 20,
  "last": false,
  "first": true,
  "sort": {
    "sorted": true,
    "unsorted": false,
    "empty": false
  },
  "numberOfElements": 10,
  "size": 10,
  "number": 0,
  "empty": false
}
...
```

-> I checked dependencies, using the 'mvn dependency:tree" and they are exactly equals.

-> I debbuged the service that is different, and saw that the object Page, at the last line of controller it's correct, so its after getting out from controller that i think some handler are modifying the object.
[Example of correct fields in a pageable endpoint, before Spring modify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3W2y.png)

-> I don't created yet a custom PageImpl because the team is using an alternatively LIB to take care of pagination (https://github.com/Nooul/spring-boot-rest-api-helpers) so that lib create the Page object.

**Spring Version** : 5.2.6.RELEASE

**Java Version** : 1.8

Anyone has any idea of ​​what can i check to solve that ? it's driving me crazy haha

Comment: In the worst case scenario you can continue using the *Step over* button to see what happens with the returned object until it is written on the response. One place to look at while debugging could be an implementation of [HttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) (probably the [MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html))

Comment: Nice tip bout the HttpMessageConverter man, and the , MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter that's it. I'm step over the debugg but I confess that is hard to understanding what is going on in this level hahaha
But i keep trying here with your tip, there rly something here on converter